# Changing the scale on a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I'm trying to give someone a view of a Linux system using python.
Here is the code I found on this site and the internet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
import csv
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_path = '/home/testdata/python/log.txt'
with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # get header from first row
    #headers = next(reader)
    # get all the rows as a list
    data = list(reader)
    #print(data)
    # transform data into numpy array
    data = np.array(data).astype(float)
plt.title('System Usage',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel("Time (h)",fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("Usage(%)",fontsize=14)    
[CPU,Memory,Disk] = plot(data)
legend([CPU,Memory,Disk], ["CPU(Used)","Memory (Mb)","Disk(Mb)"], loc=1)
show()
```

Here is the result:
[image: Chart]

How can I change the scale of the chart?  So the y-axis is from 0-100 no matter what the data is the time the chart is generated.

Comment: have you tried using `ylim` method? Eg. `plt.ylim((0,100))`

Comment: @n00b  That worked!